# VIM: How to open new file in current buffer?

Tags: vim

By default, VIM `:e` command will create a new buffer with specified file, leaving current buffer to hand around. This leads to buffers count growing very large (and that is not handy if some buffer display plugin is used, for example popular `minibufexplorer`). Is it possible to modify VIM so `:e` command will re-use current buffer? If i need two buffers, i can always create second one via `:enew` command, after all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you cannot "re-use" a buffer, a buffer in vim is

> a file loaded into memory for editing.

You could delete the current buffer then open a new, so that keep your buffers count:

```
:bd!|e /path/file
```

note that with `!`, changes on current buffer would be discarded.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it any documentation in VIM about this '|' notation? I wasn't aware that i can chain command like this.

Answer (score 11):

```
:bd!|e file
```

is the most intuitive way, but it will kill your window if you have a split. So...

```
function! ReplaceBuffer(bang, newfile)
  let curbuf = bufnr('%')
  exec "e " . a:newfile
  exec "bd" . a:bang . " " . curbuf
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 -complete=file -bang -bar BDE call ReplaceBuffer('<bang>', <f-args>)
```

Then you can do

```
:BDE ~/.vimrc
```

or

```
:BDE! ~/.vimrc
```

to load up your `.vimrc` and kill off the buffer you were in, without messing with windows.

Comment: good mention that `:bd!|e file` kills splits! i was looking for something that preserves the split layout

Comment: @jazzyfresh, try this solution, which will preserve split windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611862/vim-how-to-open-new-file-in-current-buffer/58740649#58740649

Answer (score 7):

`:e thefile | bd#`

This solution has the advantage that it will preserve windows.

1. Open "thefile" in a new buffer
2. Delete the most recent buffer (`#` is the alternate buffer)

Comment: what if there is no most recent buffer, it will throw an error.

Comment: I had two windows open. `:e filepath | bd#` destroyed my other window and opened the file, therefore windows weren't preserved. Removing `d#` from the command preserved the windows.